# Как подключиться к H2/SQLite БД в Play! Framework?

Tags: java, sqlite, playframework, h2, persistence

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь использовать в проекте персистентное хранилище. В качестве базы данных использую `H2` в файле, либо `SQLite` при следующих настройках:

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/d:/play-1.2.7/samples-and-tests/zencontact/db.sqlite"
```

А также таких:

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:db.sqlite"
```

И даже таких:

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:/d:/play-1.2.7/samples-and-tests/zencontact/db.sqlite"
```

Результат один и тот же:

```
JPA error

A JPA error occurred (Cannot start a JPA manager without a properly configured database): No datasource configured
```

При этом файл есть, это пустой файл db.sqlite, расположен по пути:
d:/play-1.2.7/samples-and-tests/zencontact/db.sqlite

ОС: Windows 7.

JDK: 1.7_079

Play! версии: 1.2.7

Что я делаю не так, и как подключить любую из двух баз данных: sqlite либо H2 persistent (file)?

Comment: смена версии Play чем-то запрещена?

Comment: @Etki - Нет. А что не так с версией?

Comment: Она первая, и ее разработка, насколько понимаю, прекратилась. Да, я знаю, что вторая уже на другом языке, но судя по истории релизов, первую особо не обновляют. Вечером попробую выкачать.